# SQLite loop statements?

Tags: sql, sqlite, loops, for-loop, range

Is there any loop statements in SQLite like `FOR .. in .. LOOP` or something like that? I have two columns `StartRange, EndRange` and I need to insert a whole sequence in the other table. So if `StartRange` is 1 and `EndRange` is 3 it's necessary to make three inserts with the values `1, 2, 3`.

Comment: I am afraid you'll need to write some imperative code to do it, SQL is generally a declarative language and only its extensions (like T-SQL, SQL/PL etc.) support control flow structures like loops. If should be easy, however, to perform the insertion in one run by using SQLite transactions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing in straight SQL if you have an extra table that holds all the integers that you need.

Suppose your `StartRange` and `EndRange` range between one and ten and you have a table like this:

```
sqlite> select i from ints;
i
1
.
.
.
10
```

This table simply contains all the possible integers that you need (i.e. one through ten).

Then if you also have this:

```
sqlite> create table t (startrange int not null, endrange int not null);
sqlite> insert into t values(1, 3);
sqlite> create table target (i int not null);
```

You can do your INSERTs into `target` with a join:

```
insert into target (i)
select ints.i
from ints join t on (ints.i >= t.startrange and ints.i <= t.endrange)
```

The result is this:

```
sqlite> select * from target;
i
1
2
3
```

Of course your real `t` would have more rows so you'd want a WHERE clause to limit which row of `t` you look at.

Similar things are often done with dates (look up "calendar tables").

So if your ranges are small (for some definition of *small*) then generate your `ints` table once, add an index to it, and use the above technique to do all the INSERTs right inside the database. Other databases have their own ways (such as PostgreSQL's [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)) to do this sort of thing without need an explicit `ints` table but SQLite is (intentionally) limited.

SQL is generally set-based so loops aren't natural. What is natural is building the appropriate sets by describing what you need. OTOH, sometimes unnatural acts are necessary and sensible.

I don't know if this makes sense for your application, I just thought I'd demonstrate how it can be done. If this approach doesn't make sense in your case then you can generate a bunch of INSERT statements outside the database.

Comment: SQLite tables have row numbers that can be used in queries.

Comment: @reinierpost Are you referring to `rowid`?

Comment: Yes. (and with your name, it is *still* too short)

Comment: @reinierpost But what if there are gaps in the `rowid`s? Or if they don't match the desired range?

Comment: True, with the explicit ranges it seems better to have explicit row numbers. But kseen needs to worry about the possibility of gaps as well.

Answer (score 24):

Apparently the looping construct in SQLite is the [WITH RECURSIVE](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html) clause.
That documentation link has sample count-to-ten code, a Mandelbrot set plotter, and a Sudoku puzzle solver, all in pure SQL.
Here's an SQLite query that computes the Fibonacci sequence to give you a feel for it:

```
sqlite> WITH RECURSIVE
   ...>   fibo (curr, next)
   ...> AS
   ...>   ( SELECT 1,1
   ...>     UNION ALL
   ...>     SELECT next, curr+next FROM fibo
   ...>     LIMIT 100 )
   ...> SELECT group_concat(curr) FROM fibo;
1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946,...
```

And here's a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

```
begin transaction;

drop table if exists naturals;
create table naturals
( n integer unique primary key asc,
  isprime bool,
  factor integer);

with recursive
  nn (n)
as (
  select 2
  union all
  select n+1 as newn from nn
  where newn < 1e4
)
insert into naturals
select n, 1, null from nn;

insert or replace into naturals
  with recursive
    product (prime,composite)
  as (
    select n, n*n as sqr
      from naturals
      where sqr <= (select max(n) from naturals)
    union all
    select prime, composite+prime as prod
    from
      product
    where
      prod <= (select max(n) from naturals)
  )
select n, 0, prime
from product join naturals
  on (product.composite = naturals.n)
;
commit;
```

Answer (score 20):

You can make loops in SQL with recursive triggers. Using *mu is too short*'s schema

```
sqlite> create table t (startrange int not null, endrange int not null);
sqlite> insert into t values(1, 3);
sqlite> create table target (i int not null);
```

we need to enable recursive triggers in SQLite:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA recursive_triggers = on;
```

Make a temporary trigger to loop up to the end of the range:

```
sqlite> create temp trigger ttrig
   ...> before insert on target
   ...> when new.i < (select t.endrange from t) begin
   ...> insert into target values (new.i + 1);
   ...> end;
```

Kick it off:

```
sqlite> insert into target values ((select t.startrange from t));
sqlite> select * from target;
3
2
1
sqlite>
```

Comment: for large ranges this results in "too many levels of trigger recursion"

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for loops in SQL, because without the WHERE clause
the command will be executed for every row in the table.
Use simply:

```sql
Update your_table set Endrange=Startrange+2
```

(and commit the changes), so each number in the `Endrange` column will be greater by 2 compared to the number in the `Startrange` column.

Comment: One of us did not understand the question. I understand that the OP wants to INSERT rows into one database table based on existing rows in a different database table. Hence I don't think UPDATE is appropriate here.

Comment: Learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your posts.