# How to SELECT values not found in a table?

Tags: sqlite

I would like to determine **particular** IDs that are not present in a table.

For example, I have the IDs 1, 2 and 3 and want to know if they exist in the table.

Essentially this would boil down to:

```
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id
      UNION
    SELECT 2 AS id
      UNION
    SELECT 3 AS id
)
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.id = id)
```

Suppose `table` had the IDs 1 and 4, then this would yield 2 and 3.

Are there more elegant / concise / faster ways to get those IDs in SQLite ?

Comment: The cardinality of a set of IDs "not present in a table" is infinite.

Comment: Duh, I meant particular IDs that I query. But yes, my question was SC-incomplete (Sheldon Cooper) :-) Edited. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: The basic principle would be to create a (temporary) table and fill it with a loop, then joining to that table. It's possible in SQLite in a way, but it certainly isn't elegant, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7370761/247702).

Comment: @Stijn My suggested workaround is a temporary temporary table as opposed to a persisted temporary table... question is which one would be faster and less tedious... probably depends on the number of values to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [compound SELECT operator EXCEPT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) allows you to do something similar to NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
SELECT 2       UNION ALL
SELECT 3
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM MyTable
```

Beginning with SQLite 3.8.3, you can use VALUES everywhere you could use SELECT, but this is just a different syntax:

```
VALUES (1),
       (2),
       (3)
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM MyTable
```

Comment: The newer syntax is nice and similar to the bigger relational database systems. Thanks !