# How to launch a long-running SQLite query in Go?

Tags: unit-testing, go, sqlite

I have a code that, when needed, interrupts a Sqlite query using a context with a deadline. My problem is to write a unit test for it: I need to launch a query that I know will run for a long time, ideally in an infinite loop, and check that it is interrupted. I use https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 to access Sqlite 3 from Go.

For example, this:

```
with recursive rec as 
   (select 1 as n union all select n + 1 from rec) 
select n from rec;
```

returns 1 immediately instead of looping, as it does in the SQLite console (is there something to do to enable CTE’s?). I also found no `sleep` function or anything similar.

Comment: why not run it in another goroutine?

Comment: Because that is not what the specification on which I am working says. I only included the relevant parts here. Basically, it boils down to: a query is run, but it should be killed if it takes too long, and I am trying to have a unit test for this.

Comment: Why test this in your code? It's a sql driver feature, it should be tested there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370761/sqlite-loop-statements the 5 times upvoted answer of Rob should provide a slow/ long enough run for a query

Comment: Unfortunately, they use CTE’s. Maybe a better question would be how to make them work in Go/Sqlite3, or why they don’t.