# How to use SQLITE Recursion to check at least once daily event in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, recursion

I am working on an android app. It has a database that stores some events(say, when the user presses a button, that special event is stored in the database) and timestamp. I want to know if the user has pressed that button daily at least once for 5 consecutive days.
I came across this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38821165/9053942) that tells me to use recursion of SQLite. I tried to use the SQLite Recursion to 'loop for 5 days' but I am getting an error. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Help.
Here is my code:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
  recursiveDailyEvents (startTimeMillis, endTimeMillis, eventCount) AS 
  (
    1612244382565, 1612330782565, (select unique count from event_tracking_table where event_tracking_table_event_id = 'post_image' and  1612244382565 <= event_tracking_table_timestamp and event_tracking_table_timestamp <= 1612330782565 ) 
    UNION ALL startTimeMillis + 86400000, endTimeMillis + 86400000 FROM recursiveDailyEvents 
    Limit 5)
    select * from recursiveDailyEvents; 
  );
```

This is the error from sqlite browser:

```
near "1612244382565": syntax error: WITH RECURSIVE
  recursiveDailyEvents (startTimeMillis, endTimeMillis, eventCount) AS
  (
    1612244382565
```

But I was expecting a table with startTimeMillis, endTimeMillis, and a count (1 or 0).
What am I doing wrong? Or how should I write this recursion?

#### Edit

Here is some sample data

```
event_tracking_table_row_id| event_tracking_table_event_id| event_tracking_table_timestamp
1|app_open|1612169104224
2|post_image|1612169437373
3|post_image|1612169738068
4|app_open|1612170216320
5|post_image|1612170507935
6|app_open|1612689116738
7|post_image|1612689316673
8|post_video|1612689579697
9|post_video|1612689609683
10|app_open|1612689664683
... ... ...
```

Here,  event_tracking_table_event_id is in millisecond.

#### Expected output

If I understand correctly, the recursion should generate a table of start time millisecond, end time millisecond, and eventCount between those time limits.
So today (2 February 20201) at some time, the epoch time was 1612244382565, and after 24 hours, the end time is 1612330782565, and so on.

```
1612244382565 , 1612330782565, 1  // 1st day start time, end time, event count
1612330782565 , 1612417182565, 0  // 2nd day start time, end time, event count
... ... // 5 rows for 5 consecutive days.
```

I am trying my best to be as clear as possible.

Comment: and what is you expected ? statment between `AS (` and `)` should be valid SELECT statment and `1612244382565, 1612330782565, ....` is not

Comment: Post sample data of the table and your expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: hello. I have updated the question as requested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the starting and ending time of each day and whether the button was clicked, you can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT date(event_tracking_table_timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') day,
       MIN(event_tracking_table_timestamp) min_time,
       MAX(event_tracking_table_timestamp) max_time,
       MAX(event_tracking_table_event_id = 'post_image') event,
FROM event_tracking_table
GROUP BY day
```

If you want the number of times the button was clicked for each day:

```
SELECT date(event_tracking_table_timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') day,
       MIN(event_tracking_table_timestamp) min_time,
       MAX(event_tracking_table_timestamp) max_time,
       SUM(event_tracking_table_event_id = 'post_image') event_count
FROM event_tracking_table
GROUP BY day
```

If you want the rows for the last 5 days, add a `WHERE` clause before `GROUP BY day`:

```
WHERE date(event_tracking_table_timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') >=
      date('now', '-5 days', 'localtime')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=63552b81c340cfddeede702e6fdcf78a).